# Linking Facebook app to existing facebook page on different accoun

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have a a Facebook app that I would like to link to a page. The problem is that they were created on different accounts. Is there a way to link the two or do I have to start from scratch? I would hate to lose the likes I have so far on the page or the users that are using the app. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your problem entirely. 
What are your problems using the app in the page now?

If having two accounts is concerning you, you can easily transfer the application to the same account that owns the page or vice versa. 
Just add the account(owning the page) as one of the Administrators of the application. Then if you want you can delete the other account (now owning the app) from the Administrators.

Comment: ok, will try this. afterwards, when someone goes to the application, they will get on the page, right?